# angular2 transition animation is not working

Tags: angular, angular-animations

I am trying to apply the angular transition to the elements but it's not working.
I  have added web-animation-js as well but still no effect. added the implementation on onMouseleave and onMouseover functions

// package.json

```
"web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
```

//list item

```
 <li class="list-group-item" (mouseover)="onMouseover()" (mouseleave)="onMouseleave()" [@usrSt]="st" [routerLink]= "['/users', i+1, person.name]" *ngFor="let person of (personsList | filter:coursestat:'chosenCourse'); let i = index">
```

// list component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-list',
  templateUrl: './list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list.component.css'],
  animations: [
    trigger('usrSt', [
      state('active', style({ 'background-color': '#cfd8dc' })),
      state('inactive', style({ 'bacckground-color': '#fff' })),
      transition('active => inactive', animate('1400ms ease-in')),
      transition('inactive => active', animate('400ms ease-out'))
    ])
  ]
})

      export class ListComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

      public personsList;
      @Input() id;
      st;
      @Input() coursestat: string;

      constructor(private getDt: InputDataService) {

      }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.personsList = this.getDt.personArr;
        console.log(this.personsList);
        this.st = Array.from(this.personsList, _ => 'active');
        console.log(this.id);
      }

      ngOnDestroy() {
        console.log('destroy list');
      }

      onMouseover() {
        this.st = 'active';
      }
      onMouseleave() {
        this.st = 'inactive';
      }

    }
```

// plunkr by [Caio Philipe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6062136/caio-filipe)

https://plnkr.co/edit/CrusaB3iCnhDPIVu2oa5?p=preview

Comment: Where is the implementation of `onMouseover` and `onMouseleave`?

Comment: updated the code

Comment: Did you added the module imports on `app.module`? `imports: [ BrowserModule, BrowserAnimationsModule ]`

Comment: yes i did. there are no console errors

Comment: I did a Plunker (https://plnkr.co/edit/CrusaB3iCnhDPIVu2oa5?p=preview) and the transition won't worked too. I tried some things but was not able to find out what is wrong. Sorry.

Comment: would you consider upvoting please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not working coz the css property `bacckground-color` is not spelled correctly. correct that and try again. It should work

Comment: lol. yeah it worked. How did I not spot that. oh god I spent whole day trying to figure what was wrong. Thanks